# Validation(ASP.NET): If this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working for me, the second expression of the ternary operator does not give me any trouble, however the first expression gives me the error:
*Validation (ASP.Net): If this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.*

```
 <asp:Label 
        ID="CategoryText" 
        CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsSkipped")) ? "CategoryCell Skipped" : "CategoryCell" %>'
        runat="server" 
        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryID").Equals(CurrentCategoryID) ? 
        "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, \"Text\").ToString() %> "
        // ^-- this is what is causing the error.
        : "<%# GenerateQuestionURL(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, \"CategoryID\").ToString(), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, \"Text\").ToString() ) %> " %>'
     />
```

Comment: @Tanner 
yes, leaving it as:
"" : "[kept this second expression the same as it was]"
works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label 
    ID="CategoryText" 
    CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsSkipped")) ? "CategoryCell Skipped" : "CategoryCell" %>'
    runat="server" 
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryID").Equals(CurrentCategoryID)     
    ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text").ToString()
    : GenerateQuestionURL(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryID").ToString(), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text").ToString()) %>'
 />
```

Its a bit of a mess though (hard to read), I would put this in a function and call it from there.